# Defining finite unions of intervals with algebraic endpoints on the reals

Tags: reference-request, model-theory, first-order-logic

I'm currently working a bit on Enderton's logic textbook (2nd ed), and, on the second chapter, he marks the following exercise on definability with an asterisk.

Let $(\mathbb{R}; +, \cdot)$ be the reals with the usual operations. Consider the usual first-order language plus symbols for multiplication and addition. Enderton asks us to show that any finite union of intervals with algebraic endpoints is definable in that structure. By this, I suppose he means that we must give a formula with free variables whose satisfaction set will be precisely the unions in question. I'm a bit at loss about how to proceed, though. It seems that one should first produce a formula which express the notion of order (but that is not too difficult), which would allow one to define the notion of an interval. Then one would need to define finite union of intervals (but that is also not difficult, I suppose; just take the disjunction of the formulas for intervals). Finally, one would also need to define algebraic numbers (but I'm not sure about how to do this). Is this right? If so, how can I define the algebraic numbers?

In addition, aside from Tarski's paper on definable sets of reals, are there any references that give a step by step proof of this theorem and its converse (that those are the only definable sets of reals)? I'm specially interested in textbooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, order can be defined by defining "nonnegative" to mean having a square root, and $x \leq y$ to mean that $\exists z (x + z = y \text{and $z$ is nonnegative})$.

Next, you'll want to establish that every integer is definable. Start with $1$.

You don't need to define a statement "$x$ is algebraic." Given a particular algebraic number $\alpha$, you merely want to define the statement "$x > \alpha$." If you let $f(x)$ be a nonzero polynomial with integer coefficients of minimal degree with $\alpha$ as a root, then $\alpha$ is a simple root of $f(x)$. (There's some algebra involved here.) So $f$ crosses the $x$-axis at $\alpha$.

Say, for instance, that $f$ is increasing near $\alpha$. (Otherwise, use $-f$.) Then take two rational numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $f$ is positive on $(\alpha,q]$ and negative on $(p,\alpha]$. The statement $x > \alpha$ can be defined by the condition "($f(x) > 0$ and $x > p$) or $x > q$".

A statement such as $x > p = a/b$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers, can itself be defined by saying that $bx > a$.

You probably need to show that $x = \alpha$ is also definable, and this can be done analogously.

The kind of statement you were talking about is then a finite combination (using connectives) of statements of the type $x > \alpha_i$ and $x = \alpha_i$, where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_r$ are a fixed list of algebraic numbers.

I'm sorry, but I don't know where this theorem might be proved.

Comment: I tried to give explicit formulas for the construction below. Do you think those would suffice?

Answer (score 1):

I claim that every interval with algebraic endpoints is definable. Taking disjunctions, it follows that also any finite union of intervals is definable.

As you noticed, the order relation is definable, then we may freely use the symbol $<$.

In a linearly ordered structure every algebraic element is definable. In fact, $a$ is algebraic if it is the solution of a formula $\varphi(x)$ with finitely many solution. So we may define $a$ saying that it is the $n$-th solution (when these are ordered by $<$) of $\varphi(x)$.

Cleary, intervals with definable endpoints are definable sets.QED

N.B. Note that you are not "defining" the set of algebraic numbers (you cannot). The answer is (has to be) non uniform.

Answer (score 1):

In order to define an arbitrary natural number $n$, we can deploy the formula $\phi_n$:

> $\phi_n := \exists x \forall y ((y \cdot x = y) \wedge n =(x + \dots + x))$

Where the expression "$x + \dots + x$"' contains $n$ iterations of $x$. We can also define $0$ directly by using:

> $\phi_0 := \forall t ((s + t) = s)$.

Using the above formulas, we can now define any particular integer. If $n$ is a positive integer, just use $\phi_n$. Otherwise, use the formula:

> $\phi_{-n} := \exists n (\phi_n \wedge \exists s (\phi_0 \wedge (w + n) = s))$.

Now we can use these formulas to define any particular rational number. Let $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$. We define the rational $\frac{n}{m} \in \mathbb{Q}$ by the formula $\phi_q$:

> $\phi_q := \exists n \exists m(\phi_n \wedge \phi_m \wedge ((n \cdot q) = m))$

And the rational $-\frac{n}{m}$ can be defined by the formula $\phi_{-q}$:

> $\phi_{-q} (q') := \exists q \phi_q \wedge (\exists s \phi_0 (s) \wedge (q' + q =s))$.

Using this, we can define the set of the algebraic roots $r$ of a polynomial using the following formula:

> $\phi_r : = \exists q_1 \dots \exists q_k (\phi_{q_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \phi_{q_k} \wedge (\exists s (\phi_0 \wedge ((q_0 + (q_1 \cdot r) + \dots + (q_k \cdot r^k)) = s)))$

Given this, we can now use the following formula to characterize the less than relation:

> $\phi_{a \leq b} : = \exists v (a+(v \cdot v) =b)$

and this one to characterize the strictly less than relation:

> $\phi_{a<b} (a, b) := \phi_{a \leq b} \wedge a \not = b$

Now, the problem with the above $\phi_r$ is that it doesn't distinguish among the roots of the given polynomial. We can, however, order its roots, and thus capture the $i$-th root of a polynomial of degree $k$ using the following formulas (I'll use $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n}r_j$ as an abbreviation for $\exists r_0 \dots \exists r_n$):

> $\phi_{r_0} : = \phi_r (r_0) \wedge \forall r (\phi_r(r) \rightarrow\phi_{r_0 < r} (r_0, r))$;
>
> $\phi_{r_1} := \phi_r (r_1) \wedge \exists r (\phi_r (r) \wedge \phi_{r < r_1}(r, r_1) \wedge \forall r' ((\phi_r (r') \wedge \phi_{r' < r_1}) \rightarrow r' = r))$;
>
> $\phi_{r_i} : = \phi_r (r_i) \wedge \sum\limits_{j=0}^{i-1}r_j (\bigwedge\limits_{j=0}^{i-1} (\phi_r (r_j) \wedge \bigwedge\limits_{0 \leq f < g <i} (r_f \not = r_g) \wedge \phi_{r_j < r_i} (r_j, r_i)) \wedge \forall r' (\phi_r (r') \wedge \phi_{r' < r_i} (r', r_i) \rightarrow \bigvee\limits_{j=0}^{i-1} (r' = r_j)))$

Now, using those formulas, we can we can define, for algebraic numbers $r_i, u_j$ (which are the  $i$-th and $j$-th root of a polynomial) the following intervals:

> $[r_i, u_j]$, $(r_i, u_j]$, $(r_i, u_j)$, $[r_i, u_j)$

by using the following formulas:

> $\phi_{(r_i,u_j)} := \exists r_i \exists u_j (\phi_{r_i} \wedge \phi_{u_j} \wedge (\phi_{r_i < b}(b)) \wedge (\phi_{b \leq u_j}(b)))$;
>
> $\phi_{(r_i,u_j]} := \exists r_i \exists u_j (\phi_{r_i} \wedge \phi_{u_j} \wedge (\phi_{r_i < b} (b)) \wedge (\phi_{b \leq u_j}(b))))$;
>
> $\phi_{[r_i,u_j)} := \exists r_i \exists u_j (\phi_{r_i} \wedge \phi_{u_j} \wedge (\phi_{r_i \leq b} (b)) \wedge (\phi_{b < u_j} (b)))$;
>
> $\phi_{[r,u]} := \exists r_i \exists u_j (\phi_{r_i} \wedge \phi_{u_j} \wedge (\phi_{r_i \leq b} (b)) \wedge (\phi_{b < u_j}(b)))$.

Finally, we can use any finite union of intervals with algebraic endpoints by simply taking disjunctions of the above formulas, e.g. $[r_i, u_j] \cup [r'_l, u'_h]$:

> $\phi_{[r_i, u_j] \cup [r'_l, u'_h]} := \phi_{[r_i, u_j]} \vee \phi_{[r'_l, u'_h]}$.

Since the above procedure is almost mechanical, it follows that any finite union of intervals with algebraic endpoints is definable.

Comment: $\phi_n$ is good. $\phi_{-n}$ needs to be changed because $0$ isn't in the language. $\phi_q$ is okay as long as it's understood to define a particular number $q$ rather than the general concept. Similarly, $\phi_r$ can only define a particular algebraic number of degree $k$. You're missing the constant term in it, and the last term should be $q_k^k$. More importantly, it's not sufficient because the same polynomial can have other roots. For $\phi_{a < b}$, add the condition $\exists w \ne 0 \ ww = v$, or change the condition to $\exists w \ne 0$. (appropriately defined) suchthat $a + ww = b$.

Comment: Again there is the problem that you don't specify $v$ is positive in the last formulas. It seems that the free variables are $a$ and $b$, but I don't see why there wouldn't just be one. Overall, the most important problem is that you can't always characterize an algebraic number $r$ the way you did. Imagine that the minimal polynomial has degree 5 and three (or five) real roots. How will you distinguish between the roots? This was the purpose of introducing the rational numbers $p$ and $q$ in my answer above.

Comment: A correction: I meant $q_k r^k$ above.

Comment: If you want to find a systematic way of determining suitable numbers $p$ and $q$, I imagine you will have to use calculus to find a lower bound on the distance between neighbouring roots of the polynomial. This seems feasible but a bit complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments, they have been really helpful! I'm working on the corrections. By suitable $p$ and $q$, you mean suitable rational numbers?

Comment: Yes. This isn't necessary to prove the theorem, but determining an explicit formula seems tricky because of the problem of multiple roots. Maybe instead, you could approach it by using formulas to distinguish the first root, the second root, etc. For example, a formula that says "$r$ is the third largest root of this polynomial."

Comment: @Dave - I made the corrections you mentioned (I think!). I'm still thinking about the problem you detected, though. Your last suggestion was to first use the formulas I wrote, then to write another formula saying that $x$ satisfies the formula and if $y$ satisfies the formula, then $y < x$ (for instance)?

Comment: You should define negative rational numbers as well. It should be $q_0 + q_1 r + \dots$. It would be simpler to define $a \leq b$ first and then $a < b$. I haven't read the ones about intervals in detail - they're a bit difficult to read. Why don't you write them using your formulas for the ordering? The main problem remains, however. If the $q_i$'s are the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $r_0$, the formula $\phi_r$ still doesn't define $r = r_0$. It defines the statement "r is a real number conjugate to $r_0$."

Comment: @Dave - I followed your suggestions (I still need to define negative rationals, but that is pretty much the same as in the case of negative integers, right?). Also, when defining the strictly less relation, I don't need to mention explicitly that $a \not = b$, right? If $v \not = 0$, then that will follow automatically, I guess. Finally, I still don't know how to solve the problem about how to capture precisely the real number I want; is that necessary in order to prove the theorem, though? I mean, can't I define the intervals with just these formulas?

Comment: Yes, you can do negative and zero rationals the same way as for integers if you like. My later suggestion was to define $a \leq b$ because it's simpler, and then to define $a < b$ as $a \leq b, a \ne b$. I don't see how you can define the intervals that way. Your formulas would mean "$a$ belongs to an interval $(r,u)$ where $r$ and $u$ are some conjugates of the numbers I want."

Comment: @Dave - And if I used yours (and I think Primo Petri's) suggestion of ordering the solutions to my formula $\phi_r$? I could say something like $\phi_{r_0}$ and for every $r$ that satisfies $\phi_{r_0}$, $r_0$ is below $r$. And then to define $r_0 < r_1$, say that $r_1$ satisfies $\phi_{r_1}$ and there is only one $r$ that also satisfies $\phi_{r_1}$ such that $r < r_1$. And so forth. And then use *those* formulas to define the intervals. Would that do the trick?

Comment: Yes, something along those lines. I think you would gain in clarity if for your formulas you wrote things like $\phi_{r_0}(x)$. That way the meaning will be clear if you need to write something like $\phi_{r_0}(y)$, $\phi_{r_0}(z)$, etc. And the same is advisable for the earlier formulas.

Comment: @Dave - Well, I modified my answer according to your suggestions; do you think this is enough to prove the theorem? Also, I tried to improve readability by introducing some abbreviations, but I'm not entirely sure I was successful about it... one of the reasons I tried not to display explicit the free variables is precisely because I thought the formulas got too cluttered. What do you think? (I may have forgotten to add the free variables in a few formulas, though)

Comment: The only problems I see are the following. The formulas don't match the right kinds of intervals. I don't know why you have $\exists v$ in the formulas at the end. I thought that was already part of the order formulas. Finally, in the formula $\phi_{r_i}$, you need to guarantee that the $r_j$'s are distinct. Besides that, I don't see any problems.

Comment: By the way, if the only purpose was to prove the theorem, I still probably would have preferred to use the rational numbers $p$ and $q$. They would be difficult to calculate explicitly, but that doesn't matter for proving the theorem.

Comment: I think I forgot to delete those $v$'s after I re-wrote those formulas. And yea, I also forgot to add a condition saying that they are all different. I'll see if I can come up with an abbreviation, that formula is already very cluttered.

Comment: @Dave - As for your suggestion to use $p$ and $q$, I couldn't figure out how to actually implement it. My knowledge of algebra is very limited, so I didn't know how to translate that to a first-order formula of the language in question. Anyway, I'd just like to add that this whole exchange has been awesome for me. Thanks tons for the patience and detailed comments!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with this.

Comment: @Dave - I decided to use a variant of the summation notation in order to introduce the difference condition for the $r_j$'s; do you think that is a good choice? (I'm aware that my choices of indexes wasn't particularly good, but I'm running out of indexes...)

Comment: I haven't seen the summation notation for "there exists" before, but if that's what's used in your book, that's fine, I suppose. The indexing is wrong, because you've included for example $r_0 \ne r_0$. Index the conjunction by $0 \leq f < g < i$.

Comment: @Dave - The summation and product notation were used in the old Polish notation, though I'm unsure if they also used in this way, to denote a sequence of quantifiers (I'm almost sure that I've already seen this somewhere, however, probably in the context of infinitary languages). And thanks for the correction on the indexing!